# A function equal to its integration?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is asked that I find a function such that $$10-f(x)=2\int_0^xf(t)dt.$$ I tried giving a new function F(x) such that ${dF(x)\over dx}=f(x)$, but all I got was a new equation $$F(x)=10x-2\int_0^xF(t)dt.$$ So how do we find such function. Thanks in advance! (I am new to differential equations, so I do not know much about the topic yet.)

Comment: The RHS is differentiable, thus so is the LHS. Differentiate both sides to reduce the problem to a first order linear differential equation with initial condition $y(0)=10$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Differentiate the equation with respect to $t$ and use the Fundamental theorem of calculus: We obtain :

$$ - \frac{ d f }{dt } = 2 f(t) $$

Next, write this equation as follows:

$$ \frac{df}{f} = - 2 dt \implies  \int \frac{df}{f} = - 2 \int dt \implies \ln f = -2t + C \implies f(t) = e^{-2t + C} $$

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea: Differentiating both sides gives
$$-f'(x) = 2f(x),$$
which has general solution $$f(x) = C e^{-2x}.$$ Evaluating both sides at a convenient value of $x$ (say, $x = 0$) determines $C$ uniquely.

Comment: Cheers, I hope you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try computing the derivative of each member. You have to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$-f'(x)=2f(x)$$

Now, divide by $f$:

$$-\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=2$$

Note that the first member is the derivative of $-\ln f(x)$. Can you continue?

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much